# Excel creation using C# - The server threw an exception. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80010105 (RPC_E_SERVERFAULT))

Tags: excel

I am getting The server threw an exception. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80010105 (RPC_E_SERVERFAULT)) exception when trying to create excel on our app server.

I have provide permissions to our service account in DCOMCNFG.exe for microsoft Excel Application

I have created the Desktop folder as per this [article](https://www.codeproject.com/Questions/87128/Unable-to-write-data-runtime-in-Excel-app-using-c) after adding desktop folder I am getting this error.

Before creating the Desktop folder I am getting different error as below:
Microsoft Excel cannot access the file 'XXX'. There are several possible reasons:

• The file name or path does not exist.
• The file is being used by another program.
• The workbook you are trying to save has the same name as a currently open workbook.

I am not able to provide full permissions to IIS AppPool\DefaultAppPool as I am not able to find this user even after enabling IIS.